# filters in the Pending Changes view of the RTC client for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rtc

I'm using RTC a lot and my project has quite a number of components. To see only the components that I'm interested in (the ones with changes) I select a filter in the RTC Pending Changes view. However, whenever I reopen Visual Studio my filter selection is gone. As I'm switching between quite a number of sandboxes and Visual Studio instances daily, having to set the filter again some 2 dozen times a day is getting quite tiresome. Is there any way to save the filter setting?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use only repository workspaces with the right components in them: when you define a repo workspace, you don't have to select *all* components from the stream.

That way, the sandboxes can load *all* components from your repo workspace, without having to set any filter.